# Use similar technology as CMMotionActivity on older iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-m7

I'm looking to use the CMMotionActivity for iPhone 5s's, but also want to be able to use similar functionality on older iPhone's, is this possible?

Could I create a less accurate alternative maybe, by tracking GPS and not using the M7 chip? Any advice/tutorials/sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own algorithm which will utilize accelerometer data and estimate number of steps taken. Its not as accurate and its not a good idea to have 2 separate logic in the same app.

In case, you want to give it a try, check this answer..[How to count steps using an Accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310250/how-to-count-steps-using-an-accelerometer)

Comment: Is it possible to find out Whether the user is moving in vehicle or not using Accelerometer when M7 Processor is not available in iOS Devices (Older iPhones) ?

Comment: logically yes. You need combination of GPS+accelerometer data.